# How is local function in C#7.0 different from a foreach or a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, anonymous-function, c#-7.0

This is more of a why question. Here it goes.

C# 7.0 added a new feature called "Local Function". Below is a code snippet.

```
public int Fibonacci(int x)
{
    if (x < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Less negativity please!", nameof(x));
    return Fib(x).current;

    (int current, int previous) Fib(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0) return (1, 0);
        var (p, pp) = Fib(i - 1);
        return (p + pp, p);
    }
}
```

What I dont understand is, its doing a recursive call to the same method. We can easily achieve this with a normal foreach. Then why a local function.

[MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) says

> methods implemented as iterators commonly need a non-iterator wrapper
>   method for eagerly checking the arguments at the time of the call.
>   (The iterator itself doesn’t start running until MoveNext is called).

Need some help in understanding the concept that it.

Comment: You can do all sort of things using a local function, it doesn't have to be recursive....

Comment: Yes @ZoharPeled, but specific to recursion, they used this example, I wonder why is that ? Just curious.

Comment: The function named `Fibonacci` is used to control the input. The local function named `Fib` imho is used to encapsulate the complex code of the logic, in this case the recursion call without bothering of the validation. You cant call `Fib`without validating 'casue of being local function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> its doing a recursive call to the same method. We can easily achieve this with a normal foreach

That are two different things: tail recursion (method calling itself at the end of the method itself) or iterating over a collection. They are not always exchangeable, but they can be used to achieve the same end result.

The local function is nothing more that a class method, with a scope limited to the method body it is declared in.

Local functions are useful for many more than recursion. It is an easy way to prevent repeating code in several blocks.

Comment: I don't think that "iterating over collection" is recursion. And tail recursion is not just "method calling itself".

Comment: @Evk I agree, I was looking for a better way to describe this. Open to suggestions. Hopefully the edit makes it better.

Comment: "The local function is nothing more that a class method, with a scope limited to the method body it is declared in." -- From the C# point of view, it is more than a method. Like lambdas were already able to, local functions can also access local variables of the containing function. At the CLR level it of course still gets translated to a method.

Comment: @hvd delegates can do the same. It is not specific to local functions, but using those variables is a cool feature indeed.